# ubuntu 14.04 lenovo z580 wireless problem

Tags: 14.04, wireless, lenovo, 14.10, ideapad

I'm having problems with wireless in **Ubuntu 14.04\14.10**, sometimes when i start-up my laptop i can't find my **WiFi** and after i restart it works just fine but after sometime it drops the connection automatically and the **Wifi** disappear again. what can i do?!! i'm using **lenovo z580**.

**sudo lshw -c Network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 08:9e:01:30:e1:79
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f3804000-f3804fff memory:f3800000-f3803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 9c:4e:36:65:3c:f8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-29-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:45 memory:f3900000-f3901fff
```

this is my **iwlwifi.conf** file

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

**tailf /var/log/syslog** output

```
Dec 22 09:54:19 adham-pc kernel: [ 1826.814334] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 22 09:54:19 adham-pc kernel: [ 1826.814336] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 22 09:54:19 adham-pc dnsmasq[1486]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc dbus[727]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -3)
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <warn> Connection disconnected (reason -3)
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 22 09:54:20 adham-pc dbus[727]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'TE-Data 1'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'TE-Data 1' has security, but secrets are required.
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'TE-Data 1' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'TE-Data'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Dec 22 09:54:23 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 (SSID='TE-Data' freq=2427 MHz)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.772607] wlan0: authenticate with 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.775798] wlan0: send auth to 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 (try 1/3)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 (SSID='TE-Data' freq=2427 MHz)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.778226] wlan0: authenticated
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.778349] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.782118] wlan0: associate with 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 (try 1/3)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.784834] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: Associated with 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.787786] wlan0: associated
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.787869] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: EG
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.804730] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: EG
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.804734] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.804735] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.804738] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.804740] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Dec 22 09:54:28 adham-pc kernel: [ 1835.804741] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 [PTK=TKIP GTK=TKIP]
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 10:c6:1f:e6:0d:18 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'TE-Data'.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> dhclient started with pid 4631
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::9e4e:36ff:fe65:3cf8 on wlan0.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::9e4e:36ff:fe65:3cf8.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: All rights reserved.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: 
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/9c:4e:36:65:3c:f8
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/9c:4e:36:65:3c:f8
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.7 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x69b90a15)
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.7 from 192.168.1.1
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.7 -- renewal in 33426 seconds.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info>   address 192.168.1.7
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.1
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.7.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dec 22 09:54:30 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.7 on wlan0.IPv4.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::9e4e:36ff:fe65:3cf8.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc avahi-daemon[763]: Registering new address record for fe80::9e4e:36ff:fe65:3cf8 on wlan0.*.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Policy set 'TE-Data 1' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc dnsmasq[1486]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc dnsmasq[1486]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc dbus[727]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Dec 22 09:54:31 adham-pc dbus[727]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 22 09:54:38 adham-pc ntpdate[4725]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.052316 sec
Dec 22 09:54:46 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 22 09:54:47 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Dec 22 09:54:50 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Dec 22 09:54:50 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Dec 22 09:54:50 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Dec 22 09:54:50 adham-pc NetworkManager[906]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Dec 22 09:55:29 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED 
Dec 22 09:55:30 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Dec 22 09:56:32 adham-pc wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a Centrino Wireless-N 2200 which uses the `iwlwifi` driver.

Open the file `iwlwifi.conf` using the command

`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Now, add the following line at the end

`options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

and save (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

The above method force disables the 802.11n protocol which sometimes causes problems with the open source drivers. 
Reboot and check whether the wifi is working.

Comment: Thank you, i will test this for today and if i face the same problem i will tell you.

Comment: still have the problem :( @rohith-madhavan